# The same updates keep getting downloaded

Tags: windows, updates

The same updates keep getting downloaded.

I have listed them below:

- Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP x86 (KB2418241)
- Security Update for .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 and 3.5 SP1 on Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP x86 (KB983583)

Answer (score 0):

Are they failing to install? That way it would constantly be trying to install them each time, they wouldn;t be re-downloaded but attempting to be re-installed.

.Net Framework can be incredibly tempremental.
You can uninstall the offending Versions and install them again, This often fails however.
I've had a few machines do this and the best way I've found to deal with it is to rip out the whole .Net framework installed packages and install them again.
There was a tool written especially to do this. You will find it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301085724/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx).

It would be worthwhile to read through the page rather than just run the tool.